# VBA Access OutputTo without the table formatting

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to export a table (actually a query, but I made it create this table just to see if something changed) to a .csv file, I was using this line to make it:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "TABLE", "TEST.csv", False
```

But it gives me error 3027 (something about read-only database or object), but I created this table, and as far as I'm concerned, it is possible to write on it!

Then I tried using this line here:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "TABLE", acFormatTXT, "test.csv"
```

And it works just fine. But When I came to see the results, they came with a table drawn around my data, and it's just horrible!

Anyways, it doesn't matter really which command I want, I'd appreciate any help as long as it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TransferSpreadsheet is for spreadsheet files. Try:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "TABLE", "d:\path\TEST.csv", False
```